# How to simulate Firefox environment in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way in which I can simulate Firefox environment in Chrome. Basically my requirement is very simple - I want to debug my script which is failing in Firefox only. So I want to debug it using chrome dev tool as its really hard to debug it in Firefox.

I am well aware of following tools -

1. Firebug
2. www.browserstack.com

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What do you find hard to understand in debugging tools for FF? IMO Chrome and FF have slightly different interface but they main idea, as breakpoints, call stack and inspector are still the same.

Comment: @GibboK my code is gets evaluated and added at the  runtime so really difficult to find it, beautify it and add debug points.

Comment: You can click "F10" then select the console tab to check what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

They both use completely different JS engines and it is not a good idea to debug even if there is a tool to do so in another browser.